# Recommendation on addressing custom routing in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

We have been using Elasticsearch for long and have come to a point where we need to do some custom routing. To place the problem in context, in one of the most important index, among many fields in a document, there are 2 fields lets call them eventkind and user. Now as it is many users are associated to a single eventkind and many eventkind to single user. Due to some requirements now we have opposing requirements and faces a issue on how to design the custom reading. If we using eventkind for routing, that will make the user spread out in many shards and hence a query that is based on user is slower and vice-versa. Would like to get some recommendation and thoughts on how one can address this.

Comment: In the Parent-Child relationship, children of a parent are automatically routed to their parent's shard, so your users could have a eventkind parent for instance, which keeps you from implementing custom logic.

Comment: well it has a heavy penalty. Its good for indexing not for search.. which according to the documentation says makes search very slow

Comment: Modelling many-to-many using ES is already a penalty ;)